# unable to read or insert data in my MySQL docker container

Tags: php, docker

This is my  Docker-compose.yml file which when i build creates an image for mysql 8.0 container and php7.3 image

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./php``
    container_name: php73
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html/

    ports:
        - 8000:80
  db:
    container_name: mysql8
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: sayam
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345@ways
    ports:
      - 6033:3306
```

This my index.php file in which i have written the code to connect to my database and read a column from my database and display on the page

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('db','sayam','12345@ways','test');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT name FROM Person_details";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['name']."&lt;br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

here I'm unable to read the data from sql code in php even though it display connected when open the web page

Comment: how do you fill your database??

Comment: are you inserting data in the DB first? cause now the code should echo "0 results"

Comment: What does "unable to read the data" means? We can't predict it. Need more info. What error do you receive? Is there any data in DB, that you trying to read? What is your index.php displaying when you execute it?

Comment: I have inserted data in my database manually already from MySQL server